# Sorting a dictionary by second value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This sorts dictionary x by the first value.

I have a dictionary such that:

```
x = {a:(1,2,3)}
```

I want to sort dictionary `x` by the 2nd value of the tuple.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, i know a dictionary can not be sorted, this is simply for user reading.  By second value, i mean the second value of the tuple, in the example dictionary, it would be "2".  The first line sorts it by "1".

Comment: Can you please include an expected output?

Comment: Minor: your code doesn't sort by the "first value" (by which I assume you mean the 0th element of the tuple), it sorts by the entire tuple.  If the 0th elements are distinct, that's the same thing, but if not it'll access the other elements to break ties.  It's the difference between `lambda x: x[1]` and `lambda x: x[1][0]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way your first example worked: `sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])`.

Note that this, like your first example, will return a list, not a dict. Dicts, being hash maps, are not ordered and can't be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a small fix to indicate the index of the item to use for sorting:

```
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
```